# How to use SQL function in reference in NHibernate?

Tags: oracle, nhibernate, mapping, fluent

I'm using Fluent NHibernate on Oracle and my problem is I have to apply lower() function on every string in where conditions. I made my own dialect that instead Oracle lower function is being used nls_lower. Database is primarly used by Microsoft Dynamics AX and this function improve performance. In standard query like this everything works fine:

```
session.QueryOver<User>()
    .Where(x => x.Name.lower() == userName.lower())
    .SingleOrDefualt<User>();
```

But how can I apply this lower() function in references? I can't find anything suitable for this and I expect It can be done somehow. I would expect something like this in mapping class but I can't find it:

```
References<Settings>(x => x.Settings)
    .Column("SettingId").lower();
```

I don't want to convert my string immediately to lowercase but I really need generate query like this:

```
select * from User where nls_lower(Name) == nls_lower("somename");
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define custom SQL to load entities. See [here](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#querysql-load).

Answer (score 1):

**nls_lower** is not a registered function in the Oracle dialect.
You can have a look in the code base in the **Oracle8iDialect** class. 
In this situation you have to register your own extension. Have a look [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/archive/2011/06/14/adding-custom-sql-functions-to-nhibernate-at-runtime.aspx).

When you've registered your dialect extension you should be able to call it this way:

```
var filter1 = Restrictions.Eq(
    Projections.SqlFunction("nls_lower", NHibernateUtil.String,
    Projections.Property<User>(x => x.Name)), userName.ToLower());

var user = session.QueryOver<User>();
user.Where(myFilter)
    .SingleOrDefualt<User>();
```

Comment: I know it's not registered function. Like I said I made subclass of Oracle10gDialect where I registered this function and override the standard lower function. This works for standard query. Question is how can I use sql function (in this case nls_lower) for generated query from references.

Comment: @oFce: sorry for my late reply. In my answer I've shown you the way you can use it with QueryOver. Haven't tried it but it should work.

Comment: Thanks for response. This will generate apply nls_lower only for property Name. I want it for all string properties. For example I have Settings entity referenced to entity User. For this 2 SQL query will be generated - for entity User and for entity Settings constrained by ID from User. And I want apply nls_lower in condition for entity Settings.